# Bower install how can I delay or pause between, or force-retry installation of dependencies?

Tags: bower

Hi I have a problem that for some reason I get blocked form a private corporate repo from installing dependencies, it seems that due to the large amount of requests I generate when running *bower install* I get blocked... this is a known issue, and fixing it could take a couple of days.

I wonder if there is a way to stop - pause and ask for user to touch a key to continue the installation?

this way I would be able to overcome this problem that is out my scope fixing and I need to install the component to work. any hint?

I get this message

```
ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads 
git@github.company.com:components/something.git", exit code of #128 client_loop: 
send disconnect: Connection reset by peer fatal: Could not read from remote 
repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the 
repository exists.
```

The repo exists and I do have access rights.

I have confirmed the cause of this issue is that private repo is wrongly cutting my connection due to the large amounts of requests, this triggers a brute force attack protection... the solution could take days to be completed in large company with processes that need to be initilizied with the corresponding teams.

A very tedious workaround is to install manually each package or to cut the bower.json package in parts and run them in separate batches.